# Representing Network Drive as Cassandra Data Directory

Tags: cassandra

I am new to cassandra. In cassandra,in order to store cores we do specify the local directory of cassandra installed machine using the property data_file_directories in Cassandra.yalm configuration file. My need is to define the  data_file_directories as **network directory**(something like 192..x.x.x/data/files/). I am using only single node cluster for rapid data write(For logging activities). As I don't rely on replication, My replication factor is 1.Any one help in defining network directory for cassandra data directory....
thanks in advance......

Answer (score 2):

1) I have stored the data for the cassandra on amazons EBS volume (Network volume), But in EC2 case it is simple as we can mount the EBS volumes on a machine as if it is a local one.

2) In other cases you will have to use NFS to configure the network directory.I have never done this but it looks straight forword.

Comment: We do (1) as well and I highly recommend it.  Create an EBS volume and mount it at /var/lib/cassandra. The advice from Cassandra/Datastax is to use the ephemeral drive, but that doesn't allow the data to persist across a stop/start of the instance.  Using the EBS volume allows you to easily resize the disk, resize the machine, etc, without having to re-replicate data.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra is firmly designed around using local storage instead of EBS or other network-mounted data.  This gives you better performance, better reliability, and better cost-effectiveness.